# urlopen error [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました　を解決したいです

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

プログラミング初心者なのです。
エラーが出て調べてもよく分からないので教えて頂けると幸いです。
pythonを使ってgit上にあるcsvを`.head`で取り出したいのですが、

> urlopen error [WinError 10054] 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました

と表示され詰まっています。
`import pandas as pd` 以下を実行するとエラーが発生します

環境
python3
jupyter notebook
IE バージョン　11.175
win10 ver1903 64ビット

```
import os
base_url = 'https://raw.github.com/practical-jupyter/sample-data/master/anime/'
anime_csv = os.path.join(base_url, 'anime.csv')
print(anime_csv)
```

```
import pandas as pd

anime_csv = os.path.join(base_url, 'anime.csv')
pd.read_csv(anime_csv).head()
```

Comment: `https://raw.github.com/practical-jupyter/sample-data/master/anime/` にアクセスすると 400エラーが返ってくるようなのですが、別のURLを参照するとどうなりますか？

Comment: 1. 質問のコードでリクエスト先となるはずなのは`os.path.join`した後の `https://raw.github.com/practical-jupyter/sample-data/master/anime/anime.csv` であり、このURLは生きています。 2. 試しにLinux上のjupyterでこのコードを実行したところエラーはでずにおそらく意図されている結果が出力されました。3. Windowsで同様の環境が手元にないのでためせていないのですが`os.path.join`をWindowsでおこなうと`/`のかわりに``\`` でパスが連結されます。ただし末尾に/がある文字列に文字列を連結した場合``\``は入らないようです。(確認したのがpython2ですが)  / ところでもし質問者さんの環境がproxy等のため直接443ポート宛の外部への接続が制限されていたりするなら質問のようなエラーが得られるかもしれませんが……